# Make an URL from a multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the code below ment to turn an array into an url that has this form: `$nopageurl = '/no/page/url?&value1=value2=&value3=&value4=';`

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($key, array('page', 'a', 'sa', 'htaccess_key'))) {
        $nopageurl .= "{$key}={$value}&";
    }
}
```

But, the $_GET array has the form:

```
Array
(
 [value1] => 0
 [value2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3113
        [1] => 3114
    )

 [value3] =>2
 [value4] =>status
);
```

And this causes the error `E_NOTICE: Array to string conversion`. What shall I do to avoid this error;

Comment: Filter the unwanted elements out of your array first (rather than using `in_array`), and then use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: what do you want exactly as output for value2?

Comment: I did use `http_build_query`, but: I need all the elements in the array _and_ I need the last param of the url out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a developer you need to address all the possibilities regarding the INPUT from the user. You can restrict the input but then you need to validate it (don't allow sub-arrays for examples) or you need to address them and find a solution for those specific cases.

You need to consider the option that the a parameter also can be an array.
Therefore, simply add a condition to check if the parameter is an array and if so, handle it as you wish. For example:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($key, array('page', 'a', 'sa', 'htaccess_key'))) {
        if(is_array($key)){
           foreach($key as $k => $v){
             $nopageurl .= "{$key}[$k]={$v}&";
           }
        } else {
           $nopageurl .= "{$key}={$value}&";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This part still gives the `Array to string conversion` error:
`else {
         $nopageurl .= "{$key}={$value}&";
  }`

Comment: Have you succeeded to solve it eventually or is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another valid way to do it:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($key, array('page', 'a', 'sa', 'htaccess_key'))) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $k => $v){
                $nopageurl .= "{$key}[$k]={$v}&";
            }
        } else {
            $nopageurl .= "{$key}={$value}&";
        }
    }
}
```